# Emulate Firebase functions with latest version of functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm currently developing Firebase functions using the Firebase emulators locally.

Every time I'm changing the logic in my functions, I want to simply run

```
firebase emulators:start
```

But it seems the latest changes are never included unless I first deploy the functions using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

This causes unnecessary deploys of unfinished code and adds a lot of time between testing each iteration.

Is there any way I can ensure the latest version of my functions are included when only running the emulators without running deploy? I've been scouring the documentation and couldn't find anything pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It sounds like you're accessing the live Cloud Functions instead of the ones running in the emulator. What output does `firebase emulators:start` show? And how are you then accessing/triggering the Cloud Functions?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! When looking at the output I noticed when I changed the name of the functions this was not reflected in the output and quickly referenced /lib/**.js and noticed my latest **.ts files were not compiled when running the emulator. I added a script that runs `tsc` before starting the emulators and can now develop efficiently, but this should frankly be included in the default behavior, so it seems like a bug in the tools.

Answer (score 0):

So after snooping around a bit it seems that my functions written in Typescript are not compiled to javascript when only starting the emulators. The javascript in `functions/lib/**.js` is run, but since the Typescript is not compiled it will always run the previous version.

This seems like a bug on Firebase's side. The natural expectation when creating a firebase folder using Firebase-cli and running emulators from the root directory would be for the Typescript to be compiled.

I've sent a bug ticket to Google Firebase and will close this question. A work around is to create a script that runs `tsc` before `firebase emulators:start`.

Answer (score 0):

I found in my package.json there's one of script named build, almost sure it's part of the firebase setup so everyone should have it too.

So just go to the functions folder and execute: "npm run build".